# How do I print just the milliseconds (time between last second and next second) of a Date object?

Tags: android, date, datetime, time

I am building a basic logging utility class and would like to log the date and time down to the millisecond of when the log entry is created.  I'm currently using:

```
Date d = new Date();
String dateToOutput = DateFormat.format( "MM-dd hh:mm:ss", d )
```

which gives me '05-23 09:05:47'.  I would like it to give me the milliseconds of when the log entry is created also and it does not appear that the DateFormat class supports millisecond retrieval.

Like the format `"MM-dd hh:mm:ss:zzz"` giving `'05-23 09:05:47.447'`.

Is it possible to do this using the DateFormat class (or a class like DateFormat)?  I recognize it is possible to create another date removing the milliseconds part of this date and then subtracting the two and printing the difference but that's just silly.  (:

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @matheszabi: Why would you put that in a comment and not an answer?  Also, why would you link to the java code docs instead of the Android-specific document at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd hh:mm:ss SSS");
String dateToOutput = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: This is exactly the class I want.  Why DateFormat doesn't support the same milliseconds output is a puzzle...  Thanks, @Pragnani!

Answer (score 0):

While I think it's silly the DateFormat class doesn't allow easy formatted output of milliseconds, I realized that obtaining the milliseconds from the timestamp is actually quite easy.  Every date object is representing a timestamp in milliseconds since 00:00 January 1, 1970 so the timestamp modulo 1000 gives the milliseconds.

I did

```
Date d = new Date();
String dateToOutput = DateFormat.format( "MM-dd hh:mm:ss", d );
dateToOutput += "." + d.getTime() % 1000;
```

which, while not ideal, works fine and gives me `'05-23 09:05:47.447'`.